# Java problem : No enclosing instance of type EmployeeTest is accessible

Tags: java

I am working with Java and trying to write a very simple test code like this to test and I thought that there was no problem but there was one problem.

```
public class EmployeeTest {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Employee[] staff = new Employee[1];
        staff[0] = new Employee("Carl Cracker", 75000);
        for (Employee e : staff)
            System.out.println("name=" + e.getName() + ",salary=" + e.getSalary());
    }
    
class Employee
{
    private String name;
    private double salary;
    public Employee(String n, double s)
    {
        name = n;
        salary = s;
    }
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
    public double getSalary()
    {
        return salary;
    }
}
}
```

Unfortunately, when I ran my code, the result is

```
No enclosing instance of type EmployeeTest is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type EmployeeTest (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of EmployeeTest).
```

I am sure that my code is very simple and easy to understand, so I am very confusing that why I had that error?

Could you please give me some comments ? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Add the attribute `static` to `class Employee` otherwise it's a *non static inner class* which needs to be instantiated from an instance of `EmployeeTest`, which does not exist in *`EmployeeTest.main`*.

Comment: thank you for your comment. You are right. After add the attribute `static` to the `class Employee`, my code ran very smooth. Your comment also easy to understand.